# Subcategory of Category in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, categories

My question is a simple fundamental question for creating a subcategory of a category in objective-c.

Consider a file named NSString+categoryName.h given as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (categoryName)
...
@end
```

with a corresponding implementation file named categoryName.m (not shown).

How would I make a subcategory if this?  Here is my initial thought (contained in a separate file called NSString+categoryName+subCategoryName.h):

```
//Should there be an import statement here to prepare compiler for appearance of categoryName?
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface categoryName (subCategoryName)
...
@end
```

possessing a separate implementation file of a similar name NSString+categoryName+subCategoryName.m:

```
// Is the import correct here?  Do I need to somehow reference this in my .h file?
#import "NSString+categoryName.h"

@implementation categoryName (subCategoryName)
...
@end
```

Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated, as always!

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? :-) It certainly sounds like it could work, but I bet (and this is just a guess) that there is no concept of a "sub-category." I could be wrong though. :-)

Comment: Can you help us out by explaining what you're trying to achieve? There are no "subcategories" in ObjC but all categories on a class are treated equally. What problem are you solving that this doesn't work for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of a "subcategory" in Obj-C.  You can create as many categories as you like for the same class, and you can adopt a naming convention like `@interface Class (category_subcategory) ... @end` or similar, but your idea of making a category on a category does not seem workable.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are not hierarchical in Objective-C.  They're just a way to put methods into groups that aren't all loaded at once.